# Zsh over-substituting aliases

Tags: alias, zsh, tmux

In Bash, running `tmux ls` works properly. However, in Zsh, I get this error:

> tmux: unknown option -- p
>   usage: list-sessions [-F format]

I suspect this is because Zsh is replacing `ls` of the command with my custom alias for `ls`:

```
alias -g ls='ls -p --color'
```

I tried setting `alias -g tmux\ ls='tmux list-sessions'`, but that didn't work.

Is there any way to change Zsh's alias expansion/substitution behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `ls` as a global alias, meaning it is expanded *anywhere* the shell sees `ls`, not just when it is used as a command. Just drop the `-g` option:

```
alias ls='ls -p --color'
```

Comment: I was using `-g` so it could be used as root. Should I just define this alias in root's `.zshrc` file?

Comment: not sure how `-g` makes it "so it could be used as root", unless you mean `sudo ls`. But that behavior -- replacing content in subcommands -- is exactly what you're now saying you don't want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I would like `sudo ls` to use the alias, but I don't want `ls` to be substituted *everywhere* like in `tmux ls`. However, this solves my problem, and I can deal with manually typing out the aliases when using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

In zsh you have global aliases when you use `alias -g`. A global alias is an alias that works not only on the beginning of your command but everywhere.
It is not what you want here!

But global aliases can be very powerful and useful. For instance:

```
alias -g L="| less" # to page the output with less
alias -g WL="| wc -l"  # to have stats from wc
alias -g CP="| xclip -f -r" # to copy output into clipboard
alias -g NU="&> /dev/null" # to remove error and standard outputs
```

To use them:

```
ps aux L  # expanded into: ps aux | less
ls -1 WL # expanded into: ls -1 | wc -l
date CP # expanded into: date | xclip -f -r
ls /foo2 /usr NU || echo okay # expanded into: ls /foo2 /usr &> /dev/null || ...
```